# Как удалить файлы из директории, которые существуют больше трёх дней?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, файлы

Как удалить те файлы из директории, которые существуют больше трёх дней?

Решение должно работать на Windows 10 и на Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь кроссплатформенным модулем [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime as DT

def del_old_files(path, min_days=3, recursive=False, verbose=0):
    p = Path(path)
    glob_pattern = "**/*" if recursive else "*"
    for f in p.glob(glob_pattern):
        if (f.is_file()
            and
            (DT.now() - DT.fromtimestamp(f.stat().st_mtime)).days >= min_days):
            if verbose > 0:
                print(f"deleting: [{str(f)}]")
            f.unlink()
```

---

Тест:

```
In [36]: del_old_files(r"C:\temp", min_days=2, verbose=1)
deleting: [C:\temp\top_1.5K_ALS_embeddings_clustered.html]
deleting: [C:\temp\top_als_embeddings.pkl]
```

PS данное решение проверяет *дату модификации* файла. Если вам надо проверять *дату создания*, то замените `f.stat().st_mtime` на `f.stat().st_ctime`